# Foreign Key в Doctrine: relation срабатывает не сразу

Tags: php, orm, mysql

Doctrine 1.2.4, PHP 5.3.3, все таблицы InnoDB. Есть три таблицы: profile, stream, event.
Связаны:

---

**Stream**

```
$this->hasMany('modelEvent as Events', array(
            'local' => 'id',
            'foreign' => 'stream_id'
));
```

---

**Profile**

```
$this->hasMany('modelEvent as Events', array(
            'local' => 'id',
            'foreign' => 'profile_id'
));
```

---

**Event**

```
 $this->hasOne('modelProfile', array(
                 'local' => 'profile_id',
                 'foreign' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->hasOne('modelStream', array(
                'local' => 'stream_id',
                'foreign' => 'id'
    ));
```

---

```
<?php
    $select = new modelEvent();
    $select -> merge ($data_event);
    $select -> modelProfile -> merge($data_profile);
    $select -> modelStream -> merge($data_stream);
    $select -> save();
?>
```

Relation срабатывает не сразу. Появляется при добавлении третьей записи, и цепляет Stream с

> stream_id = 1

и

> profile_id = 1

Я подозреваю, что я где-то крупно ошибся в документации. Подскажите где.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one-to-many

```
<?php
    $profile = new modelProfile();
    $profile -> merge($data_profile);
    $profile -> save();

    $select = new modelEvent();
    $select = $select -> getTable() -> find(0);
    $select -> modelProfile = $profile;
    $select -> save(); ?>
```

обратно

```
<?php

    $profile = new modelProfile();
    /* ... */
    $profile -> modelEvent[0] -> merge($event);
    $profile -> save();

?>
```

вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вызвать save на каждой модели отдельно:

```
$select = new modelEvent();
$select -> merge ($data_event);
$select -> modelProfile -> merge($data_profile);
$select -> modelStream -> merge($data_stream);

$select -> modelProfile -> save();
$select -> modelStream -> save();
$select -> save();
```